# Nexmo webSocket speech-to-text using voiceBase Api

Tags: vonage

I am trying to convert speech to text using voice base in nexmo. I have faced the issue in WebSocket client.
My response error is:

```
info: Server listening on:8900
info: A client is connected!
events.js:183
throw  er; // Unhandled 'error' event
Error: This socket is closed
at Socket._writeGeneric (net.js:726:18)
at Socket._write (net.js:786:8)
at doWrite (_stream_writable.js:387:12)
at writeOrBuffer (_stream_writable.js:373:5)
at Socket.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:290:11)
at Socket.write (net.js:704:40)
at WebSocketRequest.accept (/home/apptivo/Music/nexmoVoicebaseSample/Nexmo-RTS-Voicebase-master/WS-node/node_modules/websocket/lib/WebSocketRequest.js:450:21)
at WebSocketServer.handleUpgrade (/home/apptivo/Music/nexmoVoicebaseSample/Nexmo-RTS-Voicebase-master/WS-node/node_modules/websocket/lib/WebSocketServer.js:216:19)
at emitThree (events.js:141:20)
at Server.emit (events.js:217:7)
```

How to resolved this issue ???

Comment: I formatted your error message. What is still missing is the code that caused this error to show - that is where the problem may be. Please edit that into your question.

Answer (score -1):

I ran into this issue before (I am the developer of this project). Make sure your api keys are correct and are set in the .env file inside the WS-Node folder. It should be set to

```
ASR_URL={VOICEBASE_URL}
ASR_CLIENT_KEY={VOICEBASE_CLIENT_KEY}
ASR_CLIENT_SECRET={VOICEBASE_CLIENT_SECRET}
```

Comment: already we created the .env file inside the WS-Node folder and ASR_URL, ASR_CLIENT_KEY, ASR_CLIENT_SECRET are mentioned correctly into the  .env file. we faced the same issue again and again ?? what is the solution for that ?? pls suggest us ..

Comment: i just ran the demo locally and was able to get it running without any issues. Make sure the application inside the `server` folder as well as `WS-node` are both running. Use ngrok to create 2 listeners, one on port 3000, which is used for the `server` application the other on 8000, which is used for the `WS-node` folder. Also, make sure there is a .env in both applications. In the `server` folder, API_KEY
API_SECRET
APPLICATION_ID
NEXMO_NUMBER
NEXMO_DEBUG=true
LOG_LEVEL=silly
WEB_SOCKET_URL={ngrok sever- pointing to :8000}
CONFERENCE_NAME=NexmoConf
PRIVATE_KEY_PATH=
SINGLE_USER=true

Comment: not sure if it helps, but I'm running node version 8.9.1, npm version 5.2.0

Comment: we dont have start script in package.json .where are we starting the app.

Comment: you should be able to do `node app.js` in `WS-node` folder

Comment: yeah already given.Refer this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48781185/how-to-get-the-responses-from-websocket-server-to-clientsocket-io-using-nodejs  for detailed explanation of code